# How to see test result details (comments on test steps)

Tags: manual-testing, tfs, test-report

I have run a test in TFS (using Visual Studio Online 90 day trial). I let the test fail and I can see that it failed:

[image: Test result]

I can also double click the test to see more details:

[image: Test details]

However, it doesn't seem possible to see all the individual steps and the comment which I entered when executing the test:

[image: Comment entered during test execution]

**How can I access the comments for a failed test in TFS?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there are certain limitations to the online version of the tool.

Here is a screenshot of how it looks on my side in Microsoft Test Manager.

There also some information at the bottom that can`t be seen in the SS below reering to Links and History.

[image]

Comment: Agreed, I can see the comments in MS Test Manager as well.